# Extracting first element from the tuple using "fst" throwing an error "type mismatch"

Tags: f#, tuples

This is a tuple I have taken

```
 let person = ("Prathap Reddy SV", "Male", 16)
 let name = fst person   

 or 

 let person = ("Prathap", "Male", 16)
 let name = fst person
```

When I compile this that is showing me the below output

```
 > let person = ("Prathap Reddy SV", "Male", 16)
   let name = fst person

   let name = fst person
   ---------------^^^^^^

   stdin(152,16): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
   string * string    
 but given a
   string * string * int    
 The tuples have differing lengths of 2 and 3
```

But When I give tuple with two string values it is working fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The signature of `fst` is `('a * 'b -> 'a)`, that's why you receive the given error.

The function `fst` expects a tuple of two elements of whatever types, but you offer it a tuple of three elements. For tuple of three strings the error would be the same: `fst ("a","b","c")` will yield

```
stdin(1,6): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a * 'b    
but given a
    'a * 'b * 'c    
The tuples have differing lengths of 2 and 3
```

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to do `let name, _, _ = person` to get the name out of the triple.

*EDIT:* You cannot use `fst` on triple because the signature of `fst` is this: [`fst : 'T1 * 'T2 -> 'T1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370480.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
> open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection;;
> let gfst (tpl:obj) = FSharpValue.GetTupleField(tpl,0);;//index = 0

val gfst : obj -> obj

> let person = ("Prathap Reddy SV", "Male", 16);;

val person : string * string * int = ("Prathap Reddy SV", "Male", 16)

> gfst person |> unbox<string>;;
val it : string = "Prathap Reddy SV"
```

Comment: Although this works it is extremely slow, type unsafe and not idiomatic.

Comment: The result is of type `obj` that you cast to another type using `unbox` on the outside. If you get the type wrong you'll get a type error at run-time and not at compile time because your use of reflection circumvents the static type system, i.e. F# cannot prove the correctness of the code in this respect at compile time.

Comment: programer knows his using tuple types.

Comment: Use is context-dependent use, even in a strange bind without reflection and unbox, also necessarily always be the speed request.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is very old and in all honesty, I like wilx's answer best, but since nobody has mentioned using `match`...

```
let name = match person with | (a, _, _) -> a
```

or, if you prefer

```
let name = 
    match person with
    | (a, _, _) -> a
```